# Improving my own 'snap to' functionality to jQuery.Gantt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, gantt-chart

I am working with jQuery.Gantt and am attempting to add in my own snap to functionality to the bars in the chart.

My original idea was to make each cell/day within the chart .resizable, and use the 'resizable extension' for jQuery UI to make these elements snappable, which should then allow the bars to snap to the cells.

However, the cells/days were just a repeated background image within one large element, as opposed to individual HTML elements themselves (as I had thought).

My new idea is to compare the length of a re-sized bar on the chart against numerical values. For example, one cell = 24px, if the new width is >24 and <36 (as that is the cell size plus half a cell) then set the width of the element back to 24, creating the appearance of snapping backwards. To snap forwards I check the new width >36 and <=48 then set the width of the element to 48 (the size of two cells).

I have done the code for 3 cells worth of size, as you can see below:

```
var one_cell = 24;
var start_width;
var end_width;    

$(".selector").resizable(
    {
        handles 'e, w'
    },

    {
       stop: function(event, ui)
       {
           end_width = $(this).width();

           if(end_width <= one_cell)
           {
               $(this).width(one_cell); //Checks current size vs minimum size, if is less than or equal to one cell size, set to one cell size
           }
           else if(end_width > one_cell && end_width < 36)
           {
               $(this).width(one_cell);
           }
           else if(end_width > 36 && end_width <= 48)
           {
               $(this).width(48);
           }
           else if(end_width > 48 && end_width < 60)
           {
               $(this).width(48);
           }
           else if(end_width > 60 && end_width <= 72)
           {
               $(this).width(72);
           }

    }

});
```

The issue I face is that there are many cells and if I do the function this way,  it will require many lines of code and will not be efficient.

Would anyone be able to help me improve this or point me in the right direction?

I was thinking there might be a way to use the modulus operator and rounding one way or the other to create the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, I managed to figure this out myself using the code below:

```
var one_cell = 24; //Width of one cell/day
var mod;
var start_width; //Width of element before resizing
var new_width; //Width after resizing

new_width = $(this).width();
mod = new_width % one_cell;

    if(new_width <= one_cell){ //Prevents half days
            $(this).width(one_cell);
    }
    else if(mod == 0){ //Set width to new width if dragged accurately
            $(this).width(new_width);
    }
    else if(mod >1 && mod <= 23 ){ //Snap Feature
            var mult = Math.ceil(new_width / one_cell);
            $(this).width(one_cell * mult);
    }
```